# "panicked at 'assertion failed: begin <= end" when using map

Tags: rust

I've just started to touch Rust.

```
fn main() {
    let s = "aaabbb\naaaccc".to_string();
    let a: Vec<&str> = s.split('\n').map(|s| s.slice_chars(3, s.len())).collect();
    assert_eq!(a, vec!["bbb", "ccc"]);
}
```

While above code works, this doesn't. It dies at `map`.

```
#![feature(process, collections)]
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("git").args(&["status", "--porcelain"]).output().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
      panic!("failed to execute process: {}", e)
    });
    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(output.stdout.as_slice()).to_string();
    let a: Vec<&str> = s.split('\n').map(|s| s.slice_chars(3, s.len())).collect();
}
```

These are backtraces.

```
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run
     Running `target/hello_world`
thread '<main>' panicked at 'assertion failed: begin <= end', /Users/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-dist-rustc-mac/build/src/libcore/str/mod.rs:1478
stack backtrace:
   1:        0x1091266b3 - sys::backtrace::write::hc8e3cee73e646c590nC
   2:        0x10912ba0e - panicking::on_panic::h00b47941f5bc8a02HOL
   3:        0x109110de8 - rt::unwind::begin_unwind_inner::h539538ef7f909326UvL
   4:        0x1091115fe - rt::unwind::begin_unwind_fmt::h7ee8242816be0431quL
   5:        0x10912b29e - rust_begin_unwind
   6:        0x10914a487 - panicking::panic_fmt::hbdb6961ecc952cf7cSv
   7:        0x10914a35a - panicking::panic::h2860b801a6212420fQv
   8:        0x10914bfd1 - str::str.StrExt::slice_chars::hb48fc0a9452c1b98PGD
   9:        0x109110791 - str::StrExt::slice_chars::h13298185343564271120
  10:        0x10910fe14 - main::closure.2239
  11:        0x10910fd13 - iter::Map<I, F>::do_map::h17245677587133977247
  12:        0x10910e7dd - iter::Map<I, F>.Iterator::next::h11146527951811133470
  13:        0x10910dc39 - vec::Vec<T>.FromIterator<T>::from_iter::h11956274897938765189
  14:        0x10910d8bf - iter::IteratorExt::collect::h15101737251385262689
  15:        0x109106f22 - main::h2fa2dff98d35cbb8faa
  16:        0x10912d279 - rust_try_inner
  17:        0x10912d266 - rust_try
  18:        0x10912c1f2 - rt::lang_start::h660a0b4ce4c9ac40HIL
  19:        0x109106f9f - main
```

Thanks for the help!

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (522d09dfe 2015-02-19) (built 2015-02-20)
```

Comment: Please make sure to upvote useful answers and mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem! If no answer is acceptable, consider leaving comments explaining why, or edit your question to phrase the problem differently.

Answer (score 3):

You are going outside the bounds of your string. Here's an example:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "a";
    let s2 = s.slice_chars(3, s.len());
}
```

I don't really know why you are doing this slicing, so it's hard to recommend a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is because the output of `git` doesn't have the form you expect: it is probably because there is a line that has `len()` less than 3 in `s.slice_chars(3, s.len())`, and that is invalid for that function. So, you'll need to ensure you're understanding the format correctly, and/or e.g. bracket the call in an `if`, e.g. `if ... { s.slice_chars(3, s.len()) } else { "" }`.

Also, there's a domain mismatch here: `slice_chars` operates on codepoints, but `s.len()` returns the number of bytes in the string. Bytes and codepoints aren't necessarily equivalent (in fact, they are only equivalent in UTF-8 when the string is purely ASCII), so you should either use `char_len` (to use codepoints everywhere), or use `s[3..]` (to use bytes everywhere).

Comment: Thanks for let me know about domain mismatch as well!

Answer (score 2):

Your code will fail if the program's output contains lines that are less than 3 characters long (for example, lines that contain only newlines).

You haven't described what you're trying to do, but one possible solution is to filter out lines that have less than 3 characters:

```
#![feature(process, collections)]
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("git").args(&["status", "--porcelain"]).output().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
      panic!("failed to execute process: {}", e)
    });

    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(output.stdout.as_slice()).to_string();
    let a: Vec<&str> = s.split('\n')
        .filter(|s| s.len() >= 3)
        .map(|s| s.slice_chars(3, s.len()))
        .collect();
}
```